# Sum values ​only if they exist

Tags: android

- Hello everyone, I have a problem adding the values ​​of edittexts, I
  created 20 fields but I want to add only the ones I enter the values,
  example: field 1 = value 100 field 2 = value 50 field 3 = value 0
  field 4 = value 0 result = 150 how can i perform this? I used
  Double.parseDouble taking the value of edittext, tried to use the if
  else method and was unsuccessful ... The goal of my app is to create
  a table with items and values, and then turn it into PDF, thanks
  everyone!

  If I do not enter the value in any of the fields, a message appears
  toast message saying String is empty.

Comment: *tried to use the if else method and was unsuccessful* show us what you have tried.

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding required details as comment.

Comment: ready, I was able to insert the project code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not clearly get what scenario u have but it seems like you are getting input from some text fields and want to add those text fields values then u can try that

```
    Optional<String> value= Optional.ofNullable(textFieldValue)
       .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()&& s.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
       if(value.isPresent()){
           double d = Double.parseDouble(value.get()); 
           //then do your addition stuff
        }
```

Comment: First thank you very much for answering me!
I will try this method and I will return with an answer